# I think i worn out all of my Arduino Uno memory

Tags: arduino-uno, memory-usage, memory

Hi my Arduino Uno stacked with a motor driver shield was working perfectly however I am using the same board for a while now and suddenly my board stopped working.
When I upload a code no matter what code is the LED's on the board respond however the code is not executed it does nothing , the board doesn t even beep anymore.
Is there a way to clean the memory or something?
Please help.

Answer (score 4):

To check if you really cannot upload anymore (assuming it's not a software error), try the following sketch

https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/blink

This will blink the BUILTIN led.

There is very low chance to wore out your memory, you can write lots of times to it (like 10,000 times guaranteed, in practice mostly more).

But there can be another hardware problem, but first check if this simple sketch works.

Also (based on jsotola's comment), remove shields/wires.

Especially wires/shields using RX/TX since these pins are (somehow) used for loading a sketch.

Comment: @jsotola good point, I will edit my answer

Comment: Yes thank all codes that i tried work with just the Arduino Uno however when I stack the motor driver shield l239D i cant upload any code it says that an error has ocurred while uploading the sketch.

Comment: That's probably because the shield uses some GPIO pins, especially RX/TX... So that means every time you want to upload a new sketch you have to remove the shield.

Comment: Hmm thank you are you saiyng that if i upload a code to Control motors just to the Arduino board without the driver shield atached and the i connect the driver shield it Will work?

Comment: Michel keijzers thank you so much man really it worked  just fine!!! Thank you realy you do made Diference.

Comment: @Noslen Yes I'm afraid you have to do that … if it is the most helpful answer, please accept it (click on the arrow up next to the answer). Or wait a few days to see if someone else has a better answer. (and accept the one that's best at that time).